# Strange frames in movie

Tags: video

[image: Strange video]

Why is this happening? Is it some problem with one frame, which stays for few next frames, before overwritten? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the problem when encoding the video or playing it back? Either way, we'll need more details.

Comment: I have downloaded movie, that does this. I'm just asking if I can fix it somehow. If possible, I would like to get a little insight on why is this happening. (I'm a programmer, so you don't need to go easy on me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the video codec using inter-frame compression.

Basically that means that to save size / bandwidth etc most frames aren't saved as a separate picture, but as the difference from preceding and following frames.

Every now and then though, it saves a complete frame for other frames to refer to (called an I frame). If the I frame is corrupted, then the in-between frames don't have correct data to refer to, and until a new I frame comes along the error just compounds.

There's actually more to it than that - modern codecs like h.264 use motion detection to predict what the in-between frame is going to be and then can encode just the difference between the prediction and the actual image. So if a large block of the image is moving across the screen, the codec basically says take these pixels and shift them [x,y] pixels in the new frame. That's why you get that weird effect where parts of the image are sort of painted on to objects moving around in the scene. They're re-using the contents of an I frame that is wrong or not there, and applying the motion that was detected when the video was encoded.

It won't help you fix your problem, but at least now you know what's going on.